# Concatenate range-like sequence to list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like so.

```
rows = []
r1 = ('one.csv', 230)
r2 = ('two.xls', 932)
rows.append(r1)
rows.append(r2)
```

I want to add a third element to each tuple in the list, an integer key for use in a sql database. I have to wait until rows has been filled up like this before I adding the additional elements. In this example, I want the tuples to look like `('one.csv', 230, 0)` and `('two.xls', 930, 1)`. In general, these key-integers won't start at one.

It's a simple operation but I'm wondering if there's a more pythonic way to do it (i.e., not use a for loop). My other idea was to convert to a pandas data frame, but I thought the approach below was better than converting to and from a data frame.

```
rows2 = []
count = 0
for r in rows:
    rows2.append(r + (count,))
    count += 1
```

Comment: Your ways looks correct to me

Comment: you could use the `enumerate` function to achieve this.

Comment: Your approach does not produce the same result as what you said the tuples should look like. Yours starts at zero while you seem to want them to start at 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[r + (i,) for i, r in enumerate(rows, 1)]
```

prints:

```
[('one.csv', 230, 1), ('two.xls', 932, 2)]
```

The second argument to `enumerate()` is the index at which to start.

Comment: No problem, enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

This

```
[(v1, v2, i) for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(rows)]
```

With python 3, it can be shorter

```
[(*row, i) for i, row in enumerate(rows)]
```